# how to convert System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText value into string

Tags: asp.net

Hi I want to convert *System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText* value into string.

Actually I am using authentication function in which i am using HTML controls :

```
private void Authenticate_User(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText username, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText password)
  {
//-- doing some code here & Save credentials into cookies.
  }
```

***Now I am check above function on page_load :***

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string userid = Request.Cookies["UserDetails"]["UserName"].ToString();
string pass = Request.Cookies["UserDetails"]["Password"].ToString();

Authenticate_User(userid, pass);  //---- It gives some conversation error (HTML contorl to string )

}
```

**Any suggestion regarding.**

Comment: Ya, I know! but I was using: Authenticate_User(userid, pass)  many times in the project & its really hard to change the code. Any method to type cast string into htmlinput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways of doing it

Method 1:

change the parameter type of `Authenticate_User(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText username, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText password)` to `private void Authenticate_User(String username, String password)`

of if you want to typecase string to htmlinput then use this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userid = Request.Cookies["UserDetails"]["UserName"].ToString();
    string pass = Request.Cookies["UserDetails"]["Password"].ToString();

    Authenticate_User(new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText() {Value=userid, Size=userid.Length }, new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText() {Value=pass, Size=pass.Length });
};
```

Comment: works here. can you show what changes you have made. coz it works man

Comment: also try giving its length near by value

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
private void Authenticate_User(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText username, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText password)
  {
 String _username= username.Value;
 String _pass=password.Value;
//-- doing some code here & Save credentials into cookies.
  }
```

to cast you need to make a new object

```
HtmlInputText obj=new HtmlInputText();
obj.Value="";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! but I am returning this value via cookies(& it return in string). So is there any method to type cast string into htmlinput.

Comment: u can not cast but create new object and set value of that